# No Row selected when clicked on WPF DatagridRow Border

Tags: c#, wpf, border, datagridrow

I design a Datagrid based on Style set for DataGrid, DataGridRow and DataGridCell. I have set border between rows using DatagridRow Style and DGR_Border(as in code). When I click on a row it gets selected, but when I click on row borders, no row is selected, nothing happens when clicked on these borders. I want to click row and select it without forcing me to re-click just because I accidentally clicked in between the rows. Since these borders are part of DatagridRow itself, they are associated with some row and must respond to clicks or hittest? I ended up implementing a MouseDown event on Datagrid and identify the parent of the dependency object to be DatagridRow and get and set the index. This will work perfectly for Single Selection Mode but I will end up implementing the logics for Extended case, if mouse clicked with Keybaord modifiers Control and Shift.  I feel there is something simple hidden in XAML which can be set to fix this issue. Hope someone's eye will catch what I am missing. Please find below the sample with exact issue:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    x:Name="this" >
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" PanningMode="Both" >
                                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" 
                                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" 
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                                        MinWidth="40"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                        Panel.ZIndex="5"
                                        ClipToBounds="False"/>

                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter TargetName="DG_ScrollViewer" Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled">
                                <Setter TargetName="DG_ScrollViewer" Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter TargetName="DG_ScrollViewer" Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled">
                                <Setter TargetName="DG_ScrollViewer" Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

                        <!--BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource RandomColorBrushGeneratorConverter}}"-->
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        BorderThickness="0,3,0,3" 
                        BorderBrush="Black" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" 
                        Opacity="1" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>

                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border
                    IsHitTestVisible="True"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="True">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
        x:Name="_mainDataGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Dummies}"
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"
        RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        PreviewMouseDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public class Dummy
    {
        public Dummy(string f, string l, string a)
        {
            FirstName = f;
            LastName = l;
            Address = a;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Dummies = new ObservableCollection<Dummy>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Dummy dummy = new Dummy("F" + i.ToString(), "L" + i.ToString(), "ADDRESS: " + i.ToString());
                Dummies.Add(dummy);
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Dummy> Dummies { get; }

        public static T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject current)
          where T : DependencyObject
        {
            for (DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
                parent != null;
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent))
            {
                if (parent is T result)
                    return result;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Want to Avoid this and have something in XAML 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //Will end up implementing logic for Multiselection using Control and shift modifiers
            if (e.OriginalSource is DependencyObject dep &&
                GetParentOfType<DataGridRow>(dep) is DataGridRow dataGridRow)
            {
                _mainDataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGridRow.GetIndex();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**: I have already tried the solution mentioned here [DataGrid row selection not working when padding is added to cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802471/datagrid-row-selection-not-working-when-padding-is-added-to-cells) as seen in my code above and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not able to find a straight forward way, I did something else to fix it. In DataGridRow Style, I set my border transparent and enable it on row selection and Draw Bottom Border for each cell in DataGridCell Style which replicates DataGrid Row Border amd disable it on row selection.

DataGridRow Style Change:

```
    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="True"
                                 BorderThickness="0" 
                                 BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                 CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" 
                                 Opacity="1" 
                                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    
                                 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                     <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,6"/>
                                     <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                 </Trigger>
                             </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

DataGridCell Style Change:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,6"/>
                 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12"/>
                 <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    
 <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                     </Trigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
```